# Below is the code I made for detecting cycle in link list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

where I used two counters one counter is where the head pointer has reached till now and another counter goes from start to one position less than the position where the head is present to find a similar node but this code does not work why?

```
bool has_cycle(Node* head) {
    // Complete this function
    // Do not write the main method
    int i=0,j=0;
    struct Node* temp=head;
    while(head!=NULL){
        i=0;
        while(i<j){
            if(temp==head){
                return true;
            }
            temp=temp->next;
            i++;
        }
        j++;
        head=head->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `head` will always be 1-node after `temp` until `j == 2`.

Comment: Thank you for the help is got my mistake that is I didn't set temp back to head I made the right code.

Answer (score 1):

After getting the help from  David C. Rankin's answer I made the below code and it works well.

```
bool has_cycle(Node* head) {
    // Complete this function
    // Do not write the main method
    int i=0,j=0;
    struct Node* temp=head;
    struct Node* temp1=head;
    while(head!=NULL){
        i=0;
        while(i<j){
            if(temp==head){
                return true;
            }
            temp=temp->next;
            i++;
        }
        temp=temp1;
        j++;
        head=head->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Good luck with your coding.